What does "not currently ranked" mean?
When viewing a user in the reputation leagues, what does it mean when the user is noted as "Not currently ranked"?

Note that the not currently ranked message is being seen on stackoverflow.com. In the post that Andrew T linked below, Slate appears to say that the Top 400 change will only be for stackexchange.com itself, not for per-site user pages:

That's correct, @Rand, it's just stackexchange.com/leagues. The per-site users page will not be affected. – Slate Staff Mod - May 8 at 15:30

To me, "per-site" means Stack Overflow, Server Fault, Super User, etc. Am I mistaking the meaning?
Whether SE is rolling-out this change to all Stack sites or not, I believe there is a huge difference in number of users / stakeholders as far as the reputation leagues go.
The number of users invested in the Stack Overflow reputation league is quite vast... Top 400 doesn't begin to capture it when the total number of ranked users was around 1M (out of 20M total users). Top 50,000 might be a little closer... Top 100,000 closer yet.
Will the Reputation Leagues page continue to be sorted at all, or will display of the users be random? If they are sorted / displayed alphabetically, why not sort/display by reputation score? If they are sorted by reputation score, why not display their enumerated position in the list?
If SO is unable to maintain sorting/enumerating users by reputation score, how can they continue to track the reputation scores themselves? [ I am not throwing up my hands and crying, "OMG! If they stop ranking all users today they will stop tracking all reputation tomorrow!" - not at all. I am merely saying that if you have a list of 1M items, presenting a sorted list is kinda what databases are fundamentally all about. ] If displaying each user's rep percentile on their profile page is an onerous task, then drop that part - but leave the Reputation Leagues themselves sorted and enumerated.
The reputation scores set Stack Overflow apart from the Also-Rans, did they not? Spiceworks, Experts-Exchange, Reddit—all had question/answer components. Stack Overflow "won" because of the rep cred.

Possibly related: Stack Exchange reputation leagues will soon list only the top 400 users

You're not interpeting that comment correctly. It was responding to a question about whether the /users page on each site would be limited to 400 users, which it will not. It was not referring to individual user pages, which pull rank information from the leagues and is not separately calculated.

Could you clarify which "reputation league"? AFAIK, the "reputation league" link redirects to https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow, and both the menu text and the header text state "Top 400 Users" for every SE site.

I have been ranked top 10% on SO for many years. Now I am listed as "not ranked". Not only is our content sold to AI companies, we are now being discredited.
So 'we make millions selling your content so that AI can defraud and replace you, but we won't spend a dime giving you credit and are now stripping you of ranking.'
What a dystopian hellscape of a service.

Considering the range of Reputations ( 1 - 1M+), a top N% overall is far more intuitive and insightful.
